# I have a problem with the LCD

Tags: lcd

My dell laptop fell and now the screen doesn't work and the laptop makes 8 beeps when I turn it on . I tried connecting it to an external monitor but the external monitor got stuck on the dell logo , I tried to do the LCD test but it's not working for me , it's just stuck on the dell logo . Help? ( sorry if the question is not appropriate to put here , didn't know where to ask )

Comment: @EthanZ that is incorrect - 8 beep codes for a Dell refers to the LCD or Video failure for just about all models - It is just like HP beep codes, they are usually for all models

Comment: I was meaning in the regard of the test not working. There may be damage further than just the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1. Remove the AC adapter and the batter yon the laptop. With both removed, hold the power button for 10 secodns in order to reset the electronic components. It is possible that when your laptop dropped, the electronics got vaulted and may need to be reset. Once that has been completed, connect the battery or AC adapter back to the laptop and try booting up the device. During bootup, keep pressing F12 and see if you can get to the Diagnostics section inside the bios. If you are unable to see anything on the screen, try connecting the external display and see if that works.
2. Hold down the "FN" key and then turn the laptop on with the power button. Keep holding the "FN" key until you see "Diagnostic Boot Selected." Once you see this, you can release the "FN" key. This should allow you to run the LCD test and let you know what is going on with the LDC or Video card on the board.

If you are unable to do either of these, you may need to give Dell a call and see if your laptop is covered under warranty, or if they will honor the warranty it originally had. Otherwise, you will have to pay for an "Out-of-Warranty" repair in order to get it fixed.

Hopefully this helps a bit